# Generate plist with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, plist

I have an issue to generate plist file from NSMutableDictionnary. It seems to doesn't work. i have watched many example on Stackoverflow. I generate Dictionary from a plist but not plist from Dictionary.

Here is my code :

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id", @"name", nil];
NSArray *object = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value id", @"Value name", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *projectData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:object forKey:keys];

NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


for (id key in projectData)
{
    NSLog(@"projectData = key : %@, value : %@", key, [projectData objectForKey:key]);
}


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@", plistPath);
//write
[projectData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
NSMutableDictionary *newDictionnary;

//read
if ((plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"])) {

    if ([fileManager isWritableFileAtPath:plistPath]) {
        [projectData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
        newDictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        //NSLog(@"%@", plistPath);
    }
}

else {
    NSLog(@"File not found");
}
  for (id key in newDictionnary)
{
    NSLog(@"New dictionnary = key : %@, value : %@", key, [newDictionnary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Since your keys and objects are both arrays, you probably want NSMutableDictionary *projectData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:object forKeys:keys]; instead of NSMutableDictionary *projectData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:object forKey:keys]; because now you have array as a key corresponding to an array as a value.

Comment: it would probably be better to use literal syntax: `@{@"id":@"value-id", @"name":@"value-name"}`

Comment: Where ? For `newDictionary` ?

Answer (score 2):

One note: your `paths` variable is never used.

You cannot write to your bundle directory directly. You have to write either to the documents folder, the caches folder or the temp folder.

Replace `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` with `paths[0]`.

Comment: I have tested, it changed nothing

Comment: Sorry, i'm french. The file path is the same if I use `[path[0]]` or `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`

Comment: hmm, there are multiple bugs in your code. you have to debug them one-by-one

Comment: Problem resolved. I didn't open the file where i wrote my data.